# Sqlite Next button in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, button

I am trying to code a "next" button for my Sqlite db. The way I want it to work is upon entering a number it one of the entries from the db if pressed again it brings up the entry on the list for the same given number entered. However I cant get it to bring up the next entry. So far my button code looks like this. However I have tried countless way to configure it with no luck. Please help. Thanks in advance!!!

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnNext) {

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM number WHERE meter='" + editText6.getText() + "'", null);
        if (editText6.getText().toString().trim().length() >= 0) {
            c.getPosition();
            c.moveToPosition(+1);
            idNumber.setText(c.getString(0));
            editText5.setText(c.getString(6));
            editText4.setText(c.getString(5));
            editText3.setText(c.getString(4));
            editText2.setText(c.getString(3));
            editText.setText(c.getString(2));
            textView4.setText(c.getString(7));
            status.setText(c.getString(8));
            while (c.moveToNext()) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Query results are unsorted unless you use ORDER BY. And this is not how the [Cursor methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) work.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I'm rather new to android. But are you saying I simply need to add an Order by Desc to the statement and it should work? I have 3 entries and it brings up the first and last if asked I added move to first or last but I can't seem to be scroll thru the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this separate method to keep cursor open while scrolling to the next entry:

```
    final Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText6.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                    Toast ToastMessage1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please" +
                            " Enter Meter Number\nThen Press Lookup Meter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastMessage1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    View toastView1 = ToastMessage1.getView();
                    toastView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape9);
                    ToastMessage1.show();
                } else {
                    if (c.getPosition() >= 1) {
                        c.moveToPrevious();
                        idNumber.setText(c.getString(0));
                        //Must maintain this order listed below in order for clear field on focus to work properly.
                        editText6.setText(c.getString(1));
                        editText5.setText(c.getString(6));
                        editText4.setText(c.getString(5));
                        editText3.setText(c.getString(4));
                        editText2.setText(c.getString(3));
                        editText.setText(c.getString(2));
                        //To here-list order.
                        date.setText(c.getString(7));
                        status.setText(c.getString(8));
                        etAddress.setText(c.getString(9));
                    }
                    if (c.getPosition() == 0) {
                        c.close();
                        Toast ToastMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "      Last Entry Recorded      ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        ToastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        View toastView = ToastMessage.getView();
                        toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape9);
                        ToastMessage.show();
                    }
                    final Button clearBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
                    clearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v2) {
                            if (v2 == clearBtn) {
                                c.close();
                                clearText();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```